# Failing to deploy cordova app on android

Tags: cordova, gruntjs

Im a beginner to cordova and Im trying to deploy my first app with grunt. But few errors hit me on the way. I made some research but found nothing. 
I don't know if you need further details.

> Failed to restore plugin "Camera" from config.xml. You might need to
>   try adding
>       it again. Error: Error: Unpublished by habor on 2016-07-20T09:00:15.019Z
>       Discovered plugin "File" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
>       Fetching plugin "File" via npm
>       Failed to restore plugin "File" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it
>        again. Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "package". Please try adding it
>        again.
>       Discovered plugin "com.webXells.imageResizer" in config.xml. Adding it to the pr
>       oject
>       Failed to restore plugin "com.webXells.imageResizer" from config.xml. You might
>       need to try adding it again. Error: Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on http
>       s://registry.npmjs.org/com.webXells.imageResizer
>       Discovered plugin "SimpleCrypto" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
>       Failed to restore plugin "SimpleCrypto" from config.xml. You might need to try a
>       dding it again. Error: Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.
>       npmjs.org/SimpleCrypto
>       Discovered plugin "Notification" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
>       Failed to restore plugin "Notification" from config.xml. You might need to try a
>       dding it again. Error: Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.
>       npmjs.org/Notification

Comment: I solved it :) [link] (http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2016/1/how_to_create_an_awesome_hybrid_mobile_app_part2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using [this tutorial](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2016/1/how_to_create_an_awesome_hybrid_mobile_app_part2)